# Обойти блокировку Curl-запрса PHP

Tags: php, парсер, curl

Пожалуйста, помогите понять, что блокирует запрос.

Ситуация:

Источник — сайт Хофф, клиентская часть сайта динамическая, построена на API-запросах. Рисуется в моменте загрузки страницы. Нужно парсить данные, используя их API.

Запросы на JS из консоли браузера дублирую, данные получаю и всё вроде бы гут. Но с Curl — ни в какую.

Перепробовал всё что нашёл в сети: кукисы ставил, заголовки дублировал, те что отправляются из браузера. Последний код, который дал пару раз результат такой:

```
    <?php  
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
$request = array();
$request[] = 'host:hoff.ru';
$request[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$request[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
$request[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
$request[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';
$request[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36';
$request[] = 'DNT: 1';
$request[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';
$request[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8';


$url = 'https://hoff.ru/vue/catalog/section/?category_id=2768&limit=30&offset=0&showCount=1&type=product_list';
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)){
   echo 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
  $info = rawurldecode(var_export(curl_getinfo($ch),true));
  echo $data;

}
?>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Так какой результат?

Comment: Навскидку, даже невооруженным глазом, видно, что Вы не задаёте, к примеру, referrer. Кроме того, обычно, часть, построенная на API - запросах, использует POST запросы. Думаю, надо просто более аккуратно проэмултровать запрос. Подходит ли для этого CURL - не знаю, мне кажется, что не очень. Трудно поддержтвать сессии и т.п.

Comment: В консоли браузера, я вижу запрос и ответ на него в json. Хочу эмулировать такой же запрос, чтобы получить json и его уже парсить. Запрос как-то средствами PHP хочу сделать. Вот бьюсь который день. :-)

Пример запроса:

URL: https://hoff.ru/vue/catalog/section/?category_id=6604&limit=30&offset=0&showCount=1&type=product_list

Comment: Вы вполне можете записать запрос через Postman или его аналог, и затем воспроизведя через него, используя конверсию запроса в Postman в CURL. Само собой некоторые моменты придется заменить, но большую часть работы он за вас сделает.

Comment: Если запрос "виден" в браузере, то можно по нему кликнуть правой и там будет скопировать curl запрос. Его как раз можно в консоли проверить, а потом с него все вытащить в код

Comment: К сожалению, в постмане запрос блокируется. Прилетает 503 ошибка. Так же, запрос блокируется при отправке его через fetch прямо из консоли.  Отправляешь на сайте хофф — ответ 200, через любой другой — 503.